# How to estimate a country specific reproduction number (R0)

Tags: r, database, numbers

I am a new R user and I am trying to estimate a country specific reproduction number ("R0") for a disease called "Guinea worm".

I tried to install the `R0` package but I can't figure out how it works.

I have the number of cases reported in a range of years, the total population per year and an uniform distribution specifying the generation time function.

Is it possible to estimate R0 with these data? Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can get started with the estimate.R{R0} command. Please follow the exercise as the example in the respective documentation.